# typescript spread argument error with potentially falsey arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently I am getting this error, "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter." When I trying to spread an array with an unknown amount of numbers to a function.

```
function createData(
  name: string,
  jan?: number,
  feb?: number,
  mar?: number,
  apr?: number,
  may?: number,
  jun?: number,
  jul?: number,
  aug?: number,
  sep?: number,
  oct?: number,
  nov?: number,
  dec?: number
) {
  return { name, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec };
}
```

```
 const numbers: number | undefined[] = testData

  const rows = [createData("List of Numbers", ...numbers)];
```

```
{rows.map((row) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row.name}
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
              >
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.jan}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.feb}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.mar}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.apr}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.may}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.jun}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.jul}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.sep}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.oct}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.nov}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.dec}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
```

How do I get rid of the typescript error when I can't create a tuple because I am unsure if it will contain the numbers for each month. For example, if the data we query only has january and february values, then we only want to display those numbers and have the rest of the list be empty.

Comment: `const numbers: (number | undefined)[] = testData` how would you like to spread a `number`?

Comment: `numbers` must be an iterable to work with the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). So the `number` type is not going to work. How does `testData` look like?